# Using Hebrew in TexWorks

Tags: ubuntu, texworks, hebrew

I'd like to write proofs in Hebrew with TeXWorks on Ubuntu 10.4.  I'm completely new to LaTeX ... I have Hebrew support installed, but I'm not sure how to proceed regarding writing Hebrew mixed with math equations in TeXWorks.  Is there any special setup which needs to be done?

Comment: I'm guessing you've probably figured something about by now, but - is your question TeXWorks-specific, or are you asking about mixing Hebrew and math in general? Have you tried something that hasn't worked? Have you been able to enter Hebrew text at all? Details please...

Answer (score 5):

Tested with TeXworks on Ubuntu:

- Install `ivritex`

  - Via Ubuntu repositories, via package manager (Synaptic) or at the command line in a terminal window:

    ```
    sudo apt-get install ivritex
    ```
  - Or download from [ivritex.sourceforge.net](http://ivritex.sourceforge.net/) and install manually, run `sudo mktexlsr` if necessary
- Load babel with `hebrew` option:

  ```
  \usepackage[hebrew]{babel}
  ```

Complete example which I produced this way, with Hebrew and math text, using English words since I don't know Hebrew, but you see the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
Some dummy text: $y = x^2$
\[
  y = x^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: hebrew text mixed with math]

Comment: I tried:
   "sudo apt-get install ivritex"
But I'm getting 
   "E: Package 'ivritex' has no installation candidate"

Comment: I tried: "sudo apt-get install ivritex" But I'm getting "E: Package 'ivritex' has no installation candidate" – Guy Korland Jul 26 '12 at 21:25 You can get it from the ubuntu software center